# Convert NSString to NSDate in Spanish Locale

Tags: ios, localization, nsdate

I have integrate RSS feed parser into iOS application. One of the field in the received data is published date. I'm able to parse that date if the iPhone locale is English-United States. But when I change the language of iPhone to Spanish, its not able to convert the string to NSDate object.

Here's the code that I wrote:

```
NSString* dt = @"Fri, 26 Jun 2015 00:00:00";
NSDateFormatter* dtFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//set the locale to spanish
[dtFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"es"]];
[dtFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate* conDt = [dtFormatter dateFromString:dt ];
NSLog(@"%@", conDt); //This value is always (null)
```

Even after setting the locale to "es" (which is spanish), its still not able to parse it properly. How can I convert the string to date in iOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set the locale, you don't want to use the locale of the device, but rather the locale used when the string was created (because you're taking an English string and want to convert it to `NSDate` regardless of the locale of the device). In fact, it's advised to use `en_US_POSIX`:

```
[dtFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
```

See [Technical Q&A #1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html). This focuses on the Gregorian calendar issue with RFC 3999/ISO 8601 date strings, but it is applicable to language settings, too.

---

By the way, I notice that you're not setting the timezone. Often when dates do not bear any timezone information, they've been converted to GMT/UTC/Zulu. So you may want to set the timezone for your formatter, too:

```
[dtFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
```

Given that the time component of your string is "00:00:00", perhaps this isn't significant, but if dealing with datetime strings, you often want to make sure you correctly capture the timezone used within the string, as well.

Comment: Exactly. Setting the locale identifier to "es" would only make sense if you know that the server is run by a Spanish company which for some reason reports all the dates in a Spanish format - which would be very unusual.